# How to rewrite and/or redirect a url in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, url-rewriting, web-config, redirect

Here is my problem. I need two things:

I need to setup a sub domain `(sub.example.com)` to load its contents from `http://example.com/somepath` but the URL needs to remain `(sub.example.com)` for the user. This would make `http://example.com/somepath/someotherpath` equivalent to `sub.example.com/someotherpath` and so on...

And also if the user accesses `http://example.com/somepath` directly, I either need to redirect him to the sub domain or just rewrite the URL.

I am using an MVC web application hosted on Azure.

I am not good writing rewrite rules. So if someone can help me out, if this is possible and what rewrite rules I need to input into my web.config file to achieve this. Or maybe there is a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this ?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://sub.example.com/{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Sure think. Thank you for helping

Comment: Just in case this worked for you, could you mark the answer as correct? Thanks

Comment: Well this did not work. It actually messed up the site. Reading a bit about rewrite rules made me realize that the above will redirect everything to the subdomain and that not what I wanted.